# OpenCV with CMake version 3.5.2 vs CMake 2.X.X

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am at a loss to solve a particular issue I have: I cannot pinpoint the culprit.

**System:** Jetson TX1, arm64 kernel, 32b userspace, opencv4tegra

**Situation:** Have been building projects using:

```
find_package( OpenCV )
```

And this has worked fine and compiled.

**Fault:** I built from source and installed CMake 3.5.2. Now I can no-longer build any projects that depend on OpenCV. I get linker errors that point cannot find:

```
opencv_dep_cudart
```

I am assuming the issues are caused in `OpenCVCConfig.cmake`, around this point:

```
# Import target "opencv_core" for configuration "Release"
set_property(TARGET opencv_core APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
set_target_properties(opencv_core PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES_RELEASE "opencv_dep_cudart;opencv_dep_nppc;opencv_dep_nppi;opencv_dep_npps;dl;m;pthread;rt;tbb"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.12"
  IMPORTED_SONAME_RELEASE "libopencv_core.so.2.4"
  )
```

Out of the file: `/usr/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules-release.cmake`

However, this file doesn't change between CMake versions as it is an OpenCV file. So this must be how it is processed.

Reverting my CMake back to 2.8.12.2 manually allowed me to build again. Here is an example of a make command that uses OpenCV. Note the correct cuda libs:

```
Linking CXX executable DuoInterfaceTest
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/DuoInterfaceTest.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++   -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++11   CMakeFiles/DuoInterfaceTest.dir/src/mainTest.cpp.o  -o DuoInterfaceTest  -L/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/duointerface/lib/linux/arm -rdynamic libDuoInterface.a /usr/lib/libopencv_vstab.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_tegra.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_imuvstab.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_facedetect.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_esm_panorama.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_detection_based_tracker.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_video.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_ts.a /usr/lib/libopencv_superres.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_tegra.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.12 /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib/libcufft.so /usr/lib/libopencv_video.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.12 /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.12 /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib/libcudart.so /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib/libnppc.so /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib/libnppi.so /usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib/libnpps.so -ldl -lm -lpthread -lrt -ltbb -lDUO -Wl,-rpath,/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/duointerface/lib/linux/arm:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/lib
```

Thoughts? I would like to be able to keep the newer CMake on my system but don't understand enough to fix the problem. If you think this is too system-unique I will withdraw the question.

Comment: For me the same issue exists if I build projects that depend on 2.4.

Comment: Ok, as workaround setting in cmake `CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME=false` does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Michael Mairegger, you have to cmake in the build directory by doing

```
sudo cmake .. -DCUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME=false
```

But one extra thing I noticed is that if I try to `make` afterwards it won't work unless I do the `cmake` command **twice**.